# Getting the "The provided value for the 'redirect_uri' is not valid" error when I try to get the access token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, outlook-restapi

When I try to get the token I get the error:

`The provided value for the 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The value must exactly match the redirect URI used to obtain the authorization code.`

My redirect uri exactly matches so I don't understand why it is happening.

```
$TOKEN_ENDPOINT         = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$params = array(
    'grant_type'              => 'authorization_code',
    'code'                    => $azureCode,
    'clientId'                => '7c09ab71-***-****-****-53d7c4438112',
    'clientSecret'            => 'bnot*******20*[',
    'redirect_uri'            => 'https://testing.****.com/outlookOauthCallback.php',
    'urlAuthorize'            => $AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT,
    'urlAccessToken'          => $TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    'scope'                   => 'Calendars.ReadWrite User.Read'
);
$response = $client->getAccessToken($TOKEN_ENDPOINT, 'authorization_code', $params);
```

[image]

(Trust me the part I turned into stars is exactly the same because I copy pasted)

Even in the response where I returned the params it is exactly the same:

```
Array
(
    [grant_type] => authorization_code
    [code] => M51b1b*****-daeec54627b2
    [clientId] => 7c09ab71-a*****d7c4438112
    [clientSecret] => bnotxds&*&QB***cVLF20*[
    [redirect_uri] => https://testing.****.com/outlookOauthCallback.php
    [urlAuthorize] => https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
    [urlAccessToken] => https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
    [urlResourceOwnerDetails] => 
    [scope] => Calendars.ReadWrite User.Read
)
```

So how can it still be giving me this error? What am I missing here?

Comment: If you make sure same, you could try to add a trailing slash `https://testing.****.com/outlookOauthCallback.php/`.

Comment: You can try http,  http://testing.****.com/outlookOauthCallback.php

Comment: var href = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=';
href += client_id + '&resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com&redirect_uri=' + window.location.href;
window.location.href = href; What is your redirect_uri in the request url?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't specify the redirect_uri in the request url. Thank you if you will post it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @SinanSamet Glad to hear that you issue has been resolved. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need specify the redirect_uri in the request url. Something like

```
var href = 'login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/…'; href += client_id + '&resource=webdir.online.lync.com&redirect_uri=' + window.location.href;
```